# how to add NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification

Tags: iphone, nsview

i need to add NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification to my iphone application to check if user has scrolled the tableview,however to add this i think i need to import the nsview class.from where should i add this class to my project.and i need to confirm is this the best way to check if my tableview is scrolled by user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSView` does not exist on the iPhone, as it uses Cocoa-Touch and not Cocoa.

If you want to get notifications about a `UITableView`'s scroll events, just implement the `UIScrollView` delegate. It's documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate).

The delegate method you'll want to use is this one:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

}
```

There are other handy methods in there though, like:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                       withView:(UIView *)view
                        atScale:(float)scale{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

NSView has nothing to do with IOS development.

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, and UITableViewDelegate conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate. This means that the delegate you set on your UITableView will get all the calls defined for UIScrollViewDelegate, including `scrollViewDidScroll:`.